# how to sum absolute values of multiple columns in R

Tags: r, absolute-value, rowsum

I'd like to have the sum of absolute values of multiple columns with certain characteristics, say their names end in `_s`.

```
set.seed(154)
d <- data.frame(a_s = sample(-10:10,6,replace=F),b_s = sample(-5:10,6,replace=F), c = sample(-10:5,6,replace=F))
d$s <- abs(d$a_s)+abs(d$b_s)
```

where the output is column `s` below:

```
  a_s b_s  c  s
    4   8 -2 12
   10   6 -8 16
  -10  -1  1 11
    0   2  4  2
    5   1 -3  6
    8  -5  5 13
```

I can use `d$ss <- rowSums(d[,grepl('_s',colnames(d))])` to sum the values but not the absolute values.

Comment: `d$s <- rowSums(abs(d[1:2]))` or `d$s <- rowSums(abs(d[grepl('_s',colnames(d))]))`

Comment: ridiculous how I missed it! Thanks @jogo